# Open/decode Zork save file (Quetzal format) in C++

Tags: c++, save, decode, file-format, z-machine

Ok, I've started playing Zork, the old video game, and I have found that it saves its games in Quetzal file format. I have looked at the `od` output for it, but can't seem to make any sense out of it. When I Google "quetzal save file", I come across Wikipedia, which gave me this:

> The magic-number reading of the files are often shown as:
>
> > 'IFF data, Z-machine or Glulx saved game file (Quetzal)'

I am sure that it is in Quetzal format, because `file` returns: `IFF data, Z-machine or Glulx saved game file (Quetzal)`, which is the same as the magic-number (coincedence?).

So, what does magic-number mean, and how can I write a C program to decode it, presumably into an IFZF-like format?

Comment: `Magic-number reading...` is the clue here. All it means is that when `od` looked at the file, it looked at certain well-known locations in the file and found data there that identified the file as being a Quetzal file.

Comment: You will need to read this [document](http://ifarchive.giga.or.at/if-archive/infocom/interpreters/specification/savefile_14.txt) on the Quetzal file format. It will probably help to read about the Z-Machine as well as several articles mentioned on its [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-machine) page. Writing a C program to decode a Quetzal file into XML, will go much smoother once you understand the Z-Machine and the Queztal file. Another information source is [Jzip a Z-Machine emulator](http://jzip.sourceforge.net). I believe its sources includes code for reading/writing Quetzal files.

Answer (score 2):

The "magic number" refers to the unique characteristics of a file format that allow commands like `file` to identify them. For example, Quetzal save files begin with the four-byte sequence `IFZS` that identifies their Interchange File Format (IFF) document type. You can verify this with a text editor or hex dump.

You can find the [Z-machine Common Save-File Format Standard](http://www.gnelson.demon.co.uk/zspec/quetzal.html) online. You can find various compilers, tools, and specifications at the [Interactive Fiction Archive for Z-machine games](http://www.ifarchive.org/indexes/if-archiveXinfocom.html), which may help you with source code for the format. Note especially the interpreters, which include facilities for saving and restoring games.